# Instance attribute debug in python and since this attribute of the instance is empty if condition does not work as expected?

Tags: python, debugging, binary-tree, breadth-first-search

I have a problem related to class instance value problem. This code below consists of a Binary Tree class and some search methods(Depth-First-Search) which are pre-order and in-order algorithms.

The code is 100% working the problem is when I debug the root.in_order() function print out b,a,c but expected return values are d,b,a,e,c,f.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left_hand = None
        self.right_hand = None

    def insert_left(self,value):
        if self.left_hand == None:
            self.left_hand = Node(value)
        else:
            new_node = Node(value)
            new_node.left_hand = self.left_hand
            self.left_hand = new_node

    def insert_right(self,value):
        if self.right_hand == None:
            self.right_hand = Node(value)
        else:
            new_node = Node(value)
            will_be_loaded_right_child = self.right_hand
            self.right_hand = new_node
            new_node.right_hand = will_be_loaded_right_child

    def pre_order(self):
        print(self.value.value)
        print(repr(self.value))

        if self.left_hand:
            self.left_hand.pre_order()
        if self.right_hand:
            self.right_hand.pre_order()

    def in_order(self):

        if self.left_hand:
            self.left_hand.in_order()

        print(self.value)
        if self.right_hand:
            self.right_hand.in_order()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.value)

    def printAtt(self , arr = []):
        if arr.count>1:
            try:
                arr = [self.value, self.left_hand.value, self.right_hand.value]
                print(arr)
            except AttributeError:
                print("""There is nothing to show of the root |-> {} <-| 
                Node |-> {} <-| has not right or left handside value, 
                please continue to add or it 
                could be the last child:D""".format(self.value.value, self.value.value))


root = Node("a")
node_b = Node("b")
node_c = Node("c")
node_d = Node("d")
node_e = Node("e")
node_f = Node("f")

root.insert_left(node_b)
root.insert_right(node_c)

node_b.insert_right(node_d)

node_c.insert_left(node_e)
node_c.insert_right(node_f)

root.in_order()
```

Comment: It's *not* working 100%. `insert_left` and `insert_right` expect a value, not a `Node`, as an argument.

Comment: `root = Node("a")` - `root.insert_left("b")` - `root.insert_right("c")` - `root.left_hand.insert_right("d")` - `root.right_hand.insert_left("e")` - `root.right_hand.insert_right("f")` -and it works kindof, you still get another output but at least all are presented.

Comment: Yes you are right @chepner

Answer (score 0):

> Just change the last part of the script since `insert_left` and
>   `insert_right` expects value.

**Updated Version as follows:**

```
    class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left_hand = None
        self.right_hand = None

    def insert_left(self,value):
        if self.left_hand == None:
            self.left_hand = Node(value)
        else:
            new_node = Node(value)
            new_node.left_hand = self.left_hand
            self.left_hand = new_node

    def insert_right(self,value):
        if self.right_hand == None:
            self.right_hand = Node(value)
        else:
            new_node = Node(value)
            will_be_loaded_right_child = self.right_hand
            self.right_hand = new_node
            new_node.right_hand = will_be_loaded_right_child

    def pre_order(self):        
        print(self.value)        
        if self.left_hand:
            self.left_hand.pre_order()        
        if self.right_hand:
            self.right_hand.pre_order()

    def in_order(self):        
        if self.left_hand:
            self.left_hand.in_order()        
        print(self.value)
        if self.right_hand:
            self.right_hand.in_order()

    def post_order(self):       
        if self.left_hand:
            self.left_hand.post_order()
        if self.right_hand:
            self.right_hand.post_order()
        print(self.value)

root = Node("a")
root.insert_left("b")
root.insert_right("c")

node_b = root.left_hand
node_c = root.right_hand

node_b.insert_right("d")

node_c.insert_left("e")
node_c.insert_right("f")



root.in_order()
print("*"*30)
root.pre_order()
print("*"*30)
root.post_order()
```